# How to calculate total time and memory of computation

Tags: memory, monitoring

Is there a way to check how much time and memory it takes for calculation in Mathematica 9? 
I have a code where it takes about 1-2 minutes before it shows the output. I want to print the exact time and memory that calculations take in my notebook.
Thank you,

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html and https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxMemoryUsed.html

Comment: You should also be aware that Mathematica makes heavy use of caching previous calculations. If start Mathematica, evaluate `x=1` just to get it to initialize, then measure resources needed for an intense calculation and then measure resources needed to repeat that exact same calculation then those numbers may be substantially different because the second time may be reusing some of the previous results without needing to recalculate some parts of that.

Answer (score 4):

You may use[`MaxMemoryUsed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxMemoryUsed.html) for memory and and [`TimeUsed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeUsed.html) for time.

```
Quantity[TimeUsed[], "Seconds"];
memory = N@UnitConvert[Quantity[MaxMemoryUsed[Table[2.5^x, {x, 10^5}];], "Bytes"], "Megabytes"];
Quantity[TimeUsed[], "Seconds"];
time = Out[-1] - Out[-3];
{time, memory}
```

> ```
> {3.797 s, 9.9479 MB}
> ```

You can also get some real-time feedback with [`Monitor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Monitor.html).  However, some time is taken up displaying the dynamic result so this is only useful on long calculations where this additional time is negligible.

```
ClearAll[timeAndMemoryMonitor]
SetAttributes[timeAndMemoryMonitor, {HoldFirst}]
timeAndMemoryMonitor[series_] :=
 DynamicModule[
  {startTime = Quantity[TimeUsed[], "Seconds"], 
   startMemory = Quantity[MemoryInUse[], "Bytes"]},
  series = {{Quantity[0, "Seconds"], Quantity[0, "Bytes"]}};
  Dynamic[
   AppendTo[
    series, 
    {Quantity[TimeUsed[], "Seconds"] - startTime, 
     Quantity[MemoryInUse[], "Bytes"] - startMemory}];
   Refresh[
    ListLinePlot[series, 
     Mesh -> Full, 
     AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
     TargetUnits -> "Megabytes"], 
    UpdateInterval -> 2]
   ]
  ]
```

Then

```
Monitor[
 Table[2.5^x, {x, 10^5}];,
 timeAndMemoryMonitor[values]
 ]
```

> [image]

and

```
Last@values
```

> ```
> {15.765 s, 9897040 B}
> ```

Also, because the memory can decrease as the kernel dynamically manages it this method is not as robust as `MaxMemoryUsed`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions.

1. You can wrap your calculation in `Timing` which according to the overview of Time Measurement & Optimization in the [Wolfram documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TimeMeasurementAndOptimization.html) gives the "CPU time to run a command within the Wolfram Language kernel", e.g. `Timing[Select[Range[500000], PrimeQ]] // Short`
2. You can issue the `TimeUsed[]` function before and after your calculation.

Comment: Thank you, what are the units in TimeUsed[] I assume milliseconds, right?

Comment: "TimeUsed[] gives the total number of seconds of CPU time used so far in the current Wolfram System session."