# Speed up the evaluation of two million consecutive eigenvalues using `NDEigenvalues`?

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

```
 $Version
 "13.0.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (January 29, 2022)"
```

I have $28$GB  of *RAM*.

I need to calculate **two million consecutive eigenvalues** for a given billiard( e.g. circular billiard).

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}];
Region[\[ScriptCapitalR], GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]
```

[image]

```
vals = NDEigenvalues[{-1/2 Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
    u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Region[\[ScriptCapitalR]], 2000000, 
    Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.00001}}},
      "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", 
        "MaxIterations" -> Infinity}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

The above code works fine but takes an immensely long time and consumes all of my RAM, which either freezes my PC or restarts it involuntarily.

In the above code, by selecting "`MaxCellMeasure`" I can reduce the time and memory consumption, but then it limits the maximum number of eigenvalues that can be computed for this discretized system.

Is there any other way to speed up the evaluation?
Or is there any alternative way to find two million consecutive eigenvalues?

Thank you.

Comment: Region is not defined.

Comment: Dr. Evil vibes: https://imgflip.com/i/8j6rc8

Comment: @AlexTrounev, I've updated the question.

Comment: @ChrisK LOL! People are always being evil. For reference: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.4.013138

Comment: The eigenvalues of the Laplacian on a disk are known analytically.

Comment: Have you tried to estimate the memory and time with the current approach? You can see how NDEigensystem is implemented [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56320/18437). Most likely you the Arnoldi method of Eigensystem will be the bottleneck.

Comment: @Ghoster, the problem is not exactly about the disk. The problem is about how to speedup the process

Comment: @user21, How do I estimate the memory and time with the current approach without running the actual calculation? Will https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218870/84456 answer work?

Comment: @user444, start will larger `MaxCellMeasure` and fewer eigenvalues, then gradually increase them and measure the timing and memory used. Afterwards, extrapolate to the desired number of eigenvalues and `MaxCellMeasure`.

Comment: Also, you can see that the authors used some specialized algorithms for their calculations: _"Using
the very efficient scaling method of Vergini and Saraceno
[20,21] with a corner adapted Fourier-Bessel basis [22] (the
implementation is available as part of [23]) we computed
more than $2 \times 10^6$ levels for each triangle"_

Comment: Actually we can use `\[ScriptCapitalL] = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]; \[ScriptCapitalB] = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True];` and `DEigenvalues[{\[ScriptCapitalL], \[ScriptCapitalB]}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 2 10^6]` but it runs forever.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, It does give numerical values with `//N`, but as I've tested for $50$ eigenvalues, `NDEigenvalues` take $0.564904$ seconds whereas `DEigenvalues` is taking $61.6252$ seconds with the 50th eigenvalues in both the methods entirely different from one another. Why is it happening? And isn't it supposed to be a faster process?

Comment: @user444 It is not clear why do you need 2 10^6 eigenvalues for Laplacian on a disk.   Would you like to repeat research paper linked above with elliptical region? For my opinion they are not taken account that triangle region could be mapped on a disk with using some conformal map.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, in the paper, authors had diagnosed quantum chaos using the **Random Matrix Theory (RMT)** approach and found **Nearest-neighbour-Level Spacing Distribution (NLSD)**. For that reason, they needed 2*10^6 eigenvalues, as it is a statistical method. I am getting similar results with 5k eigenvalues for the billiard I am working with(Not disk). However, when you compare 5K with 2M, the sample space is not good enough. What to do now? If you have a better suggestion, I am open to it.